# Mysql : how to use like functions on integer data types to find similar numbers?

Tags: mysql, select

> in my jsp application i am storing certain pincodes in mysql. when the
>   i entered a pincode i need to get matching pincodes first and so on.

that is if i searched for 673010 i need to get display as..

673010,
673009,
673011,
673015,
673020 etc..  all the pincodes similar and adjasent to the entered pincode first ..

i used the code

```
select pincode from pintable where pincode like '%673010%' order by desc;
```

this code is not working.

it displays the matching first and then rest of the pincodes. i need to get the pincodes adjasent to the pins too. the datatype is Bigint  .. Can somebody help me out .. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is perform numerical comparisons on a field that is essentially non-numeric (I'd imagine you're storing the pincode as a `VARCHAR`). In spite of that, a possible solution might be this which will get you codes like 673012, 673013 and so on.

```
select pincode from pintable where pincode like '67301%' order by desc;
```

Comment: @Jithin In that case, this should work. `select pincode from pintable where pincode between (673010-25) and (673010+25) order by desc;` , where you can change `25` to whatever value you might feel is necessary. For example, the query I wrote will gave you values between `672985` and `673035` for the search of `673010`. You can increase or decrease the range as you see fit.

Comment: it returns error .. (check your sql syntax near desc.).

Comment: @Jithin, elementary mistake on my part. `select pincode from pintable where pincode between (673010-25) and (673010+25) order by pincode desc;` will work, tested on my local machine.

Comment: what do i do if need to display all pincodes with this result as first. ?

Comment: I think you should implement that logic in your application layer, rather than the database layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133528/discussion-between-anomitra-saha-and-jithin).